# How to run a node app which launch a desktop notifications using systemd service

Tags: linux, systemd, notifications

Based on my previous searches, I think that the answer is that I can't do that, but anyway I would like to ask because I'm not a linux pro. I have a small app made with nodejs that launch a desktop notification every second:

```
import notifier from 'node-notifier'
import {CronJob} from 'cron';

/* Create a cron job that send a desktop notification every second */
const job = new CronJob('* * * * * *', () => {

  notifier.notify({
    title: 'My notification',
    message: 'Hello, there!',
  });
}, null, true, 'America/Los_Angeles');

job.start()
```

This works well when I run `npm run start`. I want to run this using a systemd service:

```
[Unit]
Description=should run node app which launch a desktop notification
After=network.target

[Service]
Environment="DISPLAY=:0" "XAUTHORITY=/home/myuser/.Xauthority"
Type=simple
User=myuser
ExecStart=/home/myuser/.nvm/versions/node/v16.13.1/bin/node /home/myuser/notify_send/notify_node/build/index.js
Restart=on-failure

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

Several seconds after start the service, the status command shows this:

```
● runjs.service - should run node app which launch a desktop notification
     Loaded: loaded (/etc/systemd/system/runjs.service; disabled; vendor preset: enabled)
     Active: active (running) since Sun 2022-12-04 17:47:40 CET; 22s ago
   Main PID: 5606 (node)
      Tasks: 20 (limit: 18651)
     Memory: 18.1M
     CGroup: /system.slice/runjs.service
             ├─5606 /home/myuser/.nvm/versions/node/v16.13.1/bin/node /home/myuser/notify_send/notify_node/build/index.js
             ├─5633 /bin/sh -c notify-send "My notification" "Hello, there!" --expire-time "10000"
             ├─5634 notify-send My notification Hello, there! --expire-time 10000
             ├─5639 dbus-launch --autolaunch=017e96ffe51b466384d899f21cbecdc5 --binary-syntax --close-stderr
             ├─5640 /usr/bin/dbus-daemon --syslog-only --fork --print-pid 5 --print-address 7 --session
             ├─5642 /usr/bin/dbus-daemon --syslog-only --fork --print-pid 5 --print-address 7 --session
             └─5643 /usr/bin/plasma_waitforname org.freedesktop.Notifications

dic 04 17:47:40 slimbook systemd[1]: Started should run node app which launch a desktop notification.
dic 04 17:48:00 slimbook dbus-daemon[5640]: [session uid=1000 pid=5638] AppArmor D-Bus mediation is enabled
dic 04 17:48:00 slimbook dbus-daemon[5640]: [session uid=1000 pid=5638] Activating service name='org.freedesktop.Notifications' requested by ':1.0>
```

But no desktop notification is launched when service is running.

Thanks in advance.

---

**Edit**
After doing changes suggested by @edgar-magallon, add additional information:

```bash
$ sudo systemctl status runjs.service 
● runjs.service - should run node app which launch a desktop notification
     Loaded: loaded (/etc/systemd/system/runjs.service; disabled; vendor preset: enabled)
     Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Sat 2022-12-24 00:26:59 CET; 4s ago
    Process: 3281 ExecStart=/home/user/notify_send/notify_node/build/runApp (code=exited, status=127)
   Main PID: 3281 (code=exited, status=127)

dic 24 00:26:59 slimbook systemd[1]: runjs.service: Scheduled restart job, restart counter is at 5.
dic 24 00:26:59 slimbook systemd[1]: Stopped should run node app which launch a desktop notification.
dic 24 00:26:59 slimbook systemd[1]: runjs.service: Start request repeated too quickly.
dic 24 00:26:59 slimbook systemd[1]: runjs.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
dic 24 00:26:59 slimbook systemd[1]: Failed to start should run node app which launch a desktop notification.
```

and the logs:

```bash
$ sudo journalctl -xeu runjs.service
-- Support: http://www.ubuntu.com/support
-- Support: http://www.ubuntu.com/support
-- 
-- The unit runjs.service has entered the 'failed' state with result 'exit-code'.
dic 24 00:26:59 slimbook systemd[1]: runjs.service: Scheduled restart job, restart counter is at 5.
-- Subject: Automatic restarting of a unit has been scheduled
-- Defined-By: systemd
-- Support: http://www.ubuntu.com/support
-- 
-- Automatic restarting of the unit runjs.service has been scheduled, as the result for
-- the configured Restart= setting for the unit.
dic 24 00:26:59 slimbook systemd[1]: Stopped should run node app which launch a desktop notification.
-- Subject: A stop job for unit runjs.service has finished
-- Defined-By: systemd
-- Support: http://www.ubuntu.com/support
-- 
-- A stop job for unit runjs.service has finished.
-- 
-- The job identifier is 2072 and the job result is done.
dic 24 00:26:59 slimbook systemd[1]: runjs.service: Start request repeated too quickly.
dic 24 00:26:59 slimbook systemd[1]: runjs.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
-- Subject: Unit failed
-- Defined-By: systemd
-- Support: http://www.ubuntu.com/support
-- 
-- The unit runjs.service has entered the 'failed' state with result 'exit-code'.
dic 24 00:26:59 slimbook systemd[1]: Failed to start should run node app which launch a desktop notification.
-- Subject: A start job for unit runjs.service has failed
-- Defined-By: systemd
-- Support: http://www.ubuntu.com/support
-- 
-- A start job for unit runjs.service has finished with a failure.
-- 
-- The job identifier is 2072 and the job result is failed.
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: In the lines where you have `myuser` are you  actually using that name? For example, `User=myuser` should be replaced by your user (e.g. `User=biorubenfs`) as well as in the paths: `/home/myuser/.nvm/...` changes to `/home/biorubenfs/.nvm/...`. I tried my answer and works but If I try using something incorrect, such as `User=myuser` instead of my actual username I get the same logs: `Start request repeated too quickly.`

Comment: If you are using correctly your username then try removing this line: `Restart=on-failure` and run the service (it will fail, but you might get more detailed logs). After run the service run this command again: `sudo journalctl -xeu runjs.service` and add it to your question please.

Comment: It worked! All `myuser` references were right. The problem was on the `runApp` script (I didn't review the logs file before). It was logging `/home/rubenfs/notify_send/notify_node/build/runApp: line 5: node: command not found` so I changed `node ./index.js &>/home/user/logs` by `/home/myuser/.nvm/versions/node/v16.13.1/bin/node ./index.js &>/home/myuser/logs`. I'm not sure why is happening this, because when I run the script manually (without using the systemd service) , it works. I really appreciate your time, thank you so much.

Comment: Glad to know that! About the problem I'm thinking is about your node installation, maybe yo don't have it globally or the `$PATH` is not correctly set

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should specify the environment variable: `DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS` in your systemd service and use `RemainAfterExit=yes` in the section `[Service]`.

In my case, I used `echo $DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS` to get its value:

```bash
echo $DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS
#output:
unix:path=/run/user/1000/bus
```

So the systemd service would be:

```ini
[Unit]
Description=should run node app which launch a desktop notification
After=network.target

[Service]
Environment="DISPLAY=:0" "XAUTHORITY=/home/myuser/.Xauthority" "DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS=unix:path=/run/user/1000/bus"
Type=simple
User=myuser
RemainAfterExit=yes
ExecStart=/home/myuser/.nvm/versions/node/v16.13.1/bin/node /home/myuser/notify_send/notify_node/build/index.js
Restart=on-failure

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

---

Since you are running: `/home/myuser/.nvm/versions/node/v16.13.1/bin/node /home/myuser/notify_send/notify_node/build/index.js` from your systemd service I think you could get some errors (because of dependencies, but I'm not really sure, I do not know much about node) so I suggest you create a script under `/home/myuser/notify_send/notify_node/build` like this:

**runApp**

```bash
#!/bin/bash

cd "$(dirname $(realpath $0))"

node ./index.js &>/home/user/logs
```

**Systemd service**

```ini
[Unit]
Description=should run node app which launch a desktop notification
After=network.target

[Service]
Environment="DISPLAY=:0" "XAUTHORITY=/home/myuser/.Xauthority" "DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS=unix:path=/run/user/1000/bus"
Type=simple
User=myuser
RemainAfterExit=yes
ExecStart=/home/myuser/notify_send/notify_node/build/runApp
Restart=on-failure

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

*Instead of using cron-jobs in your node app you can use `Systemd Timers` whose have more features*

Comment: I did everything you wrote: edit the service (including the dbus session) and create the script `runApp` but didn't work. I know that I can use Systemd Timers but the idea was do some stuff in the node app interacting with some APIs, etc, and I feel more comfortable using javascript. Thanks anyway.

Comment: @biorubenfs In fact systemd timers are more complex, so in your case and since your familiarized with JavaScript than that's the best choice. About your problem, what's exactly the error? Why didn't work? You can see error logs by using: `sudo journalctl -xeu runjs.service` (to position the cursor at the end) or `sudo journalctl -xu runjs.service` (to see the output from the beginning)

Comment: @biorubenfs include your error in your question, I tried your code (using the systemd service of my answer) and the same code of your JavaScript and all worked correctly.

Comment: Question edited adding required information.